# Phone is discharging extremely fast.. How to stop this?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, battery, charging, motorola-moto-g2

I'm a moto gen 2 user, my phone is discharging extremely fast.. Just switches off overnight even with >50% charge .. But I'm able to charge properly.. Takes long, but its fine.. 
Tried the factory reset but both the soft and external reset not working. Please help. Customer care is a big task.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue today, apparently something wrong happens with Google Play Services last update.

Go to Settings -> Apps -> All -> Google Play Services and click on uninstall updates. Some google apps will crash but after that everything will be normal again.

Hope it help, at least it works on my MotoX

Answer (score 1):

Try to see if in the options menu, under "synchronize accounts" is everything fine.
Once I had the same issue due to three gmail accounts that were in conflict.